# Retrieving string from intent taking too long

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm retrieving extra field using

`String title = getIntent().getStringExtra(ListFragment.TITLE);`

I calculated time taken by execution of each line in onCreate() method and this particular line is taking `800 millsec` to execute which is causing noticeable lag in loading activity. Is there any other effecient way of passing a string to activity?

Comment: How did you calculate the time?

Answer (score 2):

Create public Static variable in Activity or another class, assign title value to it. You can access its value anywhere in project. This technique may help you.